# Receiving random img from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, random, ionic-framework

I can't get img from an array, I have an array with 6 variables that should be the path to the images, but the `console.log` at the end just gives me a random variable like sk11,sk15..... but they are not equal as paths to the images.

```
.controller('ArCtrl', function($scope) {

  var sk11,sk12,sk13,sk14,sk15,sk16;
  var kockice = ['sk11', 'sk12', 'sk13', 'sk14', 'sk15', 'sk16'];

  var rank = kockice[Math.floor(Math.random() * kockice.length)];
  //working good, finds random varibale in array

  if(rank === sk11) {
    sk11 = "http://localhost:8100/img/1.jpg";
    rank = sk11;

  } else if(rank === sk12) {
    sk12 = "http://localhost:8100/img/2.jpg";
    rank=sk12;

  } else if(rank === sk13) {
    sk13 = "http://localhost:8100/img/3.jpg";
    rank=sk13;

  }else if(rank === sk14) {
    sk14 = "http://localhost:8100/img/4.jpg";
    rank=sk14;

  }else if(rank === sk15) {

   sk15 = "http://localhost:8100/img/5.jpg";
   rank=sk15;

  } else if(rank === sk16){
   sk16 = "http://localhost:8100/img/6.jpg";
   rank=sk16;
  };

  console.log(rank); //gets back random from arry kockice
  console.log(sk11); //shows undefined?why
```

Comment: it never goes inside function. Put `console.log(rank)` before random rand done. what are you getting?

Comment: Put condition `if(rank === 'sk11')` string values. that will fix you problem

Comment: I could see so many conditions which are not really needed!

Comment: when you put your sk11 value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are trying to assign random image path to the `rank` variable, you should do more something like that:

```
var images = [ '1.jpg', '2.jpg', '3.jpg', '4.jpg', '5.jpg', '6.jpg' ];
var randomImage = images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)];
var rank = 'http://localhost:8100/img/' + randomImage;
```

There is no need to have all these `if` statements. Even more - it is not efficient to have them, as you would have to add them more if you get more images in the array.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Although my answer fixes your specific problem, @tdragon's solution is probably a better approach.

As @Parth Trivedi said in the comments, you need to put quotes around your variable.

Like this: `if(rank === 'sk11')`, `if(rank === 'sk12')` etc.

This is because you are currently checking if `rank` is equal to the variable `sk11`. `sk11` is not given a value anywhere.
You need to check if `rank` is equal to the string `'sk11'`.

However, your `console.log` will only return something if `rank` is equal to `'sk11'`. Otherwise, it will still be undefined.